# perl largest scalar value

Tags: perl

I have some code that's working, but spitting out a lot of warnings.

```
    foreach my $item ( sort {$item_rank{$a} <=> $item_rank{$b}} @items{
        ...
    }
```

My problem is that not every item has a rank, and so my output is littered with warnings. I want to make the items with no rank last.
I am thinking of changing the code to as follows:

```
    foreach my $item ( sort {
                              $item_rank{$a} = 99999 if(!exist $item_rank{$a});
                              $item_rank{$b} = 99999 if(!exist $item_rank{$b});
                              $item_rank{$a} <=> $item_rank{$b}} @items{
        ...
    }
```

My question is, is there a particular value that I can set it to instead of 99999, although I will never reach 99999 in my current setup, I want my code more robust.

Thanks

Comment: Don't just say `"warnings"`, say what KIND of warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it one of 2 ways:

- If you have defined max ceiling, default to it (To simplify the code, I am assuming 0 is not a valid rank)

  ```
  $max_ceiling = 99999;
  sort { ($item_rank{$a} || $max_ceiling)
     <=> ($item_rank{$b} || $max_ceiling) } @items
  ```

  Or, to avoid assigning to the hash:

  ```
  # Ideally, %item_rank should be passed as a parameter but meh.
  sub rank4comp { exist $item_rank{$_[0]} ? $item_rank{$_[0]} : 999999; }
  sort { rank4comp($a) <=> rank4comp($b) } @items;
  ```
- **Better yet, check for undefs explicitly in your expression** (remember that [sort's code block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) can be ANY expression, which returns negative, 0 or positive ala "`<=>`":

  ```
  sort { defined $item_rank{$a}
       ? defined $item_rank{$b}
       ? $item_rank{$a} <=> $item_rank{$b} : 1 : -1 } @items;
  ```

Comment: IMO the last one is perfect and first two shouldn't even be considered at all.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a clear definition of the criteria for unranked records, you might as well just separate the two groups:

```
my @unranked = grep ! defined($item_rank{$_}), keys %item_rank;
my @ranked   = grep   defined($item_rank{$_}), keys %item_rank;
```

Then you can sort as per usual, and you can even include the two arrays in the same for loop:

```
for my $item (sort ( { $item_rank{$a} <=> $item_rank{$b} } @ranked), @unranked) {
    print "$item => ", $item_rank{$item} // "N/A", "\n";
}
```

This will automatically put all your unranked items last.

Note that you need parens around the arguments to `sort` to avoid the elements of `@unranked` becoming part of the arguments for `sort`. I used the `defined-or` operator `//` to check for undefined values in the print statement.

You can even move the sort up to the `grep` statements:

```
my @unranked = grep ! defined($item_rank{$_}), keys %item_rank;
my @ranked   = sort { $item_rank{$a} <=> $item_rank{$b} }
                   grep defined($item_rank{$_}), keys %item_rank;

for my $item (@ranked, @unranked) { 
...
```